# PowerBuilder 12 Save DataWindow as Excel

Tags: powerbuilder

Our PowerBuilder application generates a report by printing a DataWindow as PDF file. Now we would like to modify the PB such that an Excel is generated instead of PDF.

In my PB code I tried using the following function:

```
public function integer save_dw_to_file (datawindow adw_datawindow, string as_filename, string as_folder);
  string ls_tmp_file_xls
  ls_tmp_file_xls = as_filename+'_temp.xls'
  adw_datawindow.saveas(ls_tmp_file_xls,Excel!,true)
  return 1
end function
```

Note: adw_datawindow is the DataWindow that I want to print; as_filename is the output filename.
However, this seems not work because I got an error when I open the file.

Do you know how to do this? Our environment:

PB Version: PB 12 Classic; Excel Version: MS Excel 2007

Comment: Error when you opened the Excel file? If so, does the error give any clues? Can you save successfully out of the IDE/DataWindow painter? Keep in mind that PDF generation works on the presentation layer, while Excel generation works on the data set, so you won't get things like formatting, drop down value conversions, customized column titles, etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should work; you should check the error code because it will have meaningful info.

It could be a permissions (file) issue, file contention issue, bad folder (invalid characters), etc., existing file that is locked. Wouldn't hurt to see if the file/folder exists first. You can check for the file using FileExists(as_filename) or you can check a folder by DirectoryExists(as_directory).

You could try Excel8! for Excel version 8 or higher but I think your Excel! should work just fine.

```
// Add saveastype as parameter to function
public function integer save_dw_to_file (datawindow adw_datawindow, &
                                         string as_filename, &
                                         string as_folder, &
                                         SaveAsType sat_SaveType)

int li_rc
string ls_tmp_file
ls_tmp_file = as_filename

// add file extension based on saveastype
choose case sat_SaveType
case Excel!, Excel5!, Excel8!
   ls_tmp_file += '_temp.xls'
case PDF!
   ls_tmp_file += '_temp.pdf'
end choose

if FileExists ( ls_tmp_file ) Then  
   if MessageBox('File already exists','Would you like to replace: ' + &
       ls_tmp_file + '?', Question!, YesNo!, 2) = 2 then
      return -1
   end if
end if 

// save type based on parameter to function
li_rc = adw_datawindow.saveas(ls_tmp_file, sat_SaveType, true)
if li_rc = -1 then
    MessageBox('Error saving file','Unable to save file: ' + ls_tmp_file)
end if

return li_rc
```